# How to evaluate the integral $\int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\exp(-\frac{a-bx}{1-x^2})dx$ with $a\geq b>0$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was asked to evaluate this integral.

$$
\int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-\frac{a-bx}{1-x^2}}dx
$$
where $a\geq b>0$.

I tried to use contour integral. While the singularities are over the real axis and the interval is finite. Can someone give any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**not an answer**

We want to evaluate
$$
J := \int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-\frac{a-bx}{1-x^2}}dx
$$

I tried the case $a=3,b=2$.  Others should proceed similarly, but with different numerical answers.  Numerically, $J \approx 0.0695$.

In the complex plane, with the interval $[-1,1]$ removed, there is an analytic function
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{3-2z}{1-z^2}\right)
$$
Choose the branch so that, when approaching $[-1,1]$ from below, the limit is positive, and when approaching $[-1,1]$ from above, the limit is negative.

Now integrate
$$
I_\varepsilon = \oint_{\gamma[\varepsilon]} f(z)\;dz,
$$
where $\gamma[\varepsilon]$ is a curve like this:

[image]

taken in the counter-clockwise direction.  As the parameter $\epsilon$ goes to zero, the two horizontal segments approach the interval $(-1,1)$, one from below going left to right, and one from above going right to left.

Since $f$ is analytic outside the curve, with residue $i$ at $z=\infty$, the integral is computed by Cauchy:  $I_\epsilon = 2\pi$.

As $\varepsilon \to 0$, of course each of the horizontal segments approaches $J \approx 0.0695$.

Can the limiting values of the two circles be computed?  I don't know.  These are essential singularities for the function $f$.  (They may not converge at all, but at least their sum does.)

Numerically, it seems:
  The circle around $1$ approaches approx. $1.13$, the circle around $-1$ approaches approx. $5.02$.  So as expected the total is $2 \times 0.07 + 1.13 + 5.02 = 6.29 \approx 2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you. This is nice.